# get an error while trying to run create-react-app

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-config-react-app: Integrity verification failed for sha512-RH5VoLdx5LlLPQd0obvUkjOqvjal21IwlkRdoRan7bLL5jfifEBPyvsO5r5eJAgQlQEm8b5AHM7m5ev2Rk3v6A== (/home/dolapo/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/44/7e/55a0b771e4b94b3d0774a1bbd49233aabe36a5db523096445da116a7edb2cbe637e27c404fcafb0ee6be5e240810950126f1be401ccee6e5ebf6464defe8)
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @Dez linux mint